# Unable to Create Swift Class with non ASCII characters

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header, objective-c-swift-bridge

I'm trying to create the following class:

```
@objc(GameFacade)
class GameFaçade: NSObject {
   ...
}
```

However when I try to compile I get the following error:

> Parameter of 'swift_name' attribute must be an ASCII identifier string

This error is on my `-Swift.h` header, the generated code is

```
SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED("GameFaçade")
@interface GameFacade : NSObject
...
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

It seems to be the bug reported in [rdar://22737851](https://openradar.appspot.com/22737851).

Is there any way around this using non-ASCII characters?

Comment: `Is there any way around this?` Don't use non-ASCII characters.

Comment: I've clarified my question

Comment: If you can't deal with using non-ASCII characters, seems you'll have to wait for the bug to be resolved.  Or... can't you just not generate the `-Swift.h` header?  The real problem is that *Objective-C* (and other languages) don't know how to deal with non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Looks like the issue (and solution) are pretty much knowns, it's been reported to Apple and the answer to "it hurts when I do this" is, "don't do that"  Either don't use non-ASCII characters, or don't generate the bridging header.